# How to add the {fmt} library?

Tags: c++, fmt

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (`vs2022 17.4.4`) and I want to use the {fmt} library in my project. I cloned the repository from [{fmt} GitHub](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), and followed the following procedure:

1. I added `...\include\fmt` to `Project → Properties → C/C++ → Additional Include Directories`.
2. I added `...\src` to `Project → Properties → Linker → General → Additional Library Directories`.
3. I added `fmt.cc;format.cc;os.cc;` to `Project → Properties → Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies`.

However, `#include <fmt/core.h>` still occurs an error.

> Cannot open source file 'fmt/core.h'

Could you tell me what to do?

Comment: src folder contains .cc files which are source files, not library files. Additional library directories should contain paths to static/dynamic libraries.

Comment: Why are you adding `.cc`s directly to your project? Use CMake to build libfmt as intended, then add the resulting library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `fmt` twice. Either

1. Include directory `...\include\fmt` and `#include <core.h>`

or

2. Include directory `...\include` and `#include <fmt/core.h>`

Presumably option 2 is preferred.

Your other settings don't look correct to me either. Why are you adding .cpp files as libraries? Either you need to compile the .cpp file in which case they should be added to the project just like any other .cpp files. Or there is an actual library to build in which case you need to set up a separate project to build it (assuming that it hasn't been built already).

Answer (score 3):

Additional library directories should contain paths to static/dynamic libraries, not source files.

1. Add `PATH_TO_FMT_ROOT/include` to `C/C++ > Additional Include Directories`.
2. Add the source files provided in the archive (`.cc` files in `PATH_TO_FMT_ROOT/src`) to your project's src folder. OR
   Build a library out of the source files and include it by providing its path and name in Linker options.
3. Build the project.